# Pass variable value to batch file

Tags: excel, ms-access, batch-file, vba

Can't pass the variable value to a batch file:

VBA code executed when clicked on an Access 2007 form button.

```
Private Sub OpenWB(var1 As String)
    Dim RetVal
    RetVal = Shell("S:\WildlifeHealth\Idaho\Incoming\test.bat var1", vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Code from sub routine that calls OpenWB:

```
idahofile = "S:\WildlifeHealth\Idaho\Incoming\test.xls”
Call OpenWB(idahofile)
```

test.bat file:

```
Call %1
```

Returns “var1” instead of "S:\WildlifeHealth\Idaho\Incoming\test.xls”

If test.bat file:

```
Call S:\WildlifeHealth\Idaho\Incoming\test.xls, file opens.
```

So how can I pass the value of var1 instead of the name var1.

I am trying to find a work around to Access keeping a process of excel running in the process window after the user closes excel. It is not closed programmatically through VBA. I thought if I could pass the pathname that was selected in a dialog box in Access to a batch file and open it there (hence not from Access but the command line), my problem would be solved. But alas, I can’t seem to pass the variable value.

Ideas anyone?

Perhaps there is another programming language that can handle this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried replacing this:

```
"S:\WildlifeHealth\Idaho\Incoming\test.bat var1"
```

with this:

```
"S:\WildlifeHealth\Idaho\Incoming\test.bat " & var1
```

in the `Shell` function of your `OpenWB` sub?

To understand what's going on, your original code was constructing the command inside a string literal, i.e. a fixed string. So it looked that you really wanted to pass the argument called `var1`. In reality what you wanted to do is *replace* the value of `var1` with the parameter to your sub called `var1`. This means that you wanted to construct your batch command at run-time, which means you needed to append the supplied value of `var1` to the batch file. Therefore, your original code was hardcoding `var1` as a parameter whereas the updated code is appending whatever the run-time value of `var1` is to the batch file as a parameter.

Comment: Yes! Because I want to learn: why did that work? Also, I changed "call" to "start" in the batch file so that the batch window would close after opening the spreadsheet. Thanks.

Comment: Makes sense. I appreciate you providing me with a learning moment. :-)

Comment: @user12059: No worries, it's my pleasure.